# I'm getting an error in the Display page of my PHP form

Tags: php

I am trying to make a form using PHP that after pressing the submit button, displays the data a person has entered but I'm getting an error that states Undefined array Key "ticket4" in the display page due to Drodown menu and the 4th option of the checkbox not getting displayed on the display page.

Code for dropdown menu:

```
 <p>Please select the number of tickets :</p>
          <select name "dropdown">
          <option value="Select" >Select</option>
          <option value="ticket1" > 1 </option>
          <option value="ticket2" > 2 </option>
          <option value="ticket3" > 3 </option>
          <option value="ticket4" > 4 </option>
          </select><br><br>
```

---

Code for dropdown menu on display page:

```
The number of tickets that you have selected are : <?php
 
if (isset($_POST["ticket1"])) {
    echo $_POST["ticket1"];
    }
    else if (isset($_POST["ticket2"])) {
    echo $_POST["ticket2"];
    }
    else if (isset($_POST["ticket3"])) {
    echo $_POST["ticket3"];
    }
    else{
    echo $_POST["ticket4"];
    }
    ?><br>
```

---

Code for checkbox menu:

```
<p>Which movies would you like to watch :</p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="movie1" name="movie1" value="Stowaway">
      <label for="movie1"> Stowaway </label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="movie2" name="movie2" value="Tenet">
      <label for="movie2"> Tenet </label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="movie3" name="movie3" value="Home Invasion">
      <label for="movie3"> Home Invasion </label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="movie4" name="movie4" value="Rush">
      <label for="movie4"> Rush </label><br><br>
```

---

Code for checkbox menu on display page:

```
The movies which you would like to watch are : <?php
   

     if (isset($_POST["movie1"])) {
        echo $_POST["movie1"];
        }
        else if (isset($_POST["movie2"])) {
        echo $_POST["movie2"];
        }
        else if (isset($_POST["movie3"])) {
        echo $_POST["movie3"];
        }
        else {
        echo $_POST["movie4"];
        }
      ?><br>
```

Comment: And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @aynber Undefined array Key "ticket4"

Comment: That would be because the name of the select is "dropdown" (maybe, since you forgot the equal sign), not ticket4. Ticket4 would be the value of "dropdown"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `name` attribute in your `select` element like so:

`<select name="example">`

On the back end you can use this (in this case "example") as a reference:
`$_POST['example']`.

the value is determined by the options value. For more information of the select element and how the `name` attribute is used, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select